# Password protected redirect with php

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot seem to find the answer to this anywhere. The closest I have managed to do is to password protect a page with php, but every solution I've found in that regard I haven't been able to get to work properly. Basically I am making a web-based puzzle game. I have the current version set up with javascript to forces you to enter a password to get to the next level. I would like something similar in php because you can easily view the password if you look at the page source. I really like what this js code does, unfortunately I can't find any resources how to do that with php. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<SCRIPT>
        function passWord() {
        var testV = 1;
        var pass1 = prompt('Enter the Code',' ');
        while (testV < 3) {
        if (!pass1) 
        history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "1234") {
        alert('It came unlocked!');
        window.open('sample-level.htm');
        break;
        } 
        testV+=1;
        var pass1 = 
        prompt('That is not the correct answer.','Password');
        }
        if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
        history.go(-1);
        return " ";
        } 
    </SCRIPT>
```

I just need to be able to protect the next destination page, not the current one.

Comment: There are thousands of PHP login tutorials that cover this.

Comment: Missing a `&` => `if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" && testV ==3)` as a sidenote.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   Also password is "1234" in one part of the code and "password" in another.

Comment: @developerwjk so the single ampersand is good then?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I was just seeing what else I could find wrong with the code beyond that.

Comment: This code works just fine on all the sites I've tested it on. Only problem I've had is with mobile, the password never works on the first try, only if you enter it again. I don't want to keep this js for this because you can get the password by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP sessions. You'll need to create a Database, create a table in that database to store the username, password and perhaps email. Then you'll want to create a file to connect to the database. Include that file in your login/password form. All the code and information is a bit much to put here but the link below is very strait forward tutorial and should get you started.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/user-membership-with-php--net-1523

Comment: Each page will have a different password. Is there no way to have php validate a form and, if you typed the correct answer, it allows the button to send you to the destination?

Comment: I will say, though, thanks for this suggestion, it makes sense to do it like this.

Comment: Well you could just store the password in the database and compare the two and then load the page if they answer correctly. Sessions would be important if security were a serious issue.